# JavaScript Source Code Analyzer

Tags: javascript, code-analysis

Does anyone know of a good, extensible source code analyzer that examines JavaScript files?

Comment: What are you looking for as far as analysis?

Comment: Pretty much, the typical errors and compatibility issue analysis but also the ability to examine naming conventions and style as well.

Comment: Can you provide an example code analyzer for a different language?

Comment: An example of what I would like to see is something like MS's StyleCop or FXCop but for JavaScript instead of C# or MSIL bytecode.

Comment: After years of using both JSHint and JSLint, I moved the answer to JSHint. JSLint, in my opinion, is too opinionated and strict.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In the interest of keeping this question up-to-date, there is a fork of JSLint called [JSHint](http://jshint.com/). An explanation of why JSHint was created can be found [here](http://anton.kovalyov.net/2011/02/20/why-i-forked-jslint-to-jshint/), but to summarize:

> JSHint is a fork of JSLint, the tool
>   written and maintained by Douglas
>   Crockford. JSLint served me well for
>   quite some time but in the past few
>   months it has gotten uncomfortably
>   opinionated and hostile towards your
>   code. It is quickly transforming from
>   a tool that helps developers to
>   prevent bugs to a tool that makes sure
>   you write your code like Douglas
>   Crockford.

Comment: Ha, a down vote :-) Was that you Douglas?

Comment: While this is an older question by now, I moved the answer to JSHint.  I respect both JSLint and JSHint; however, JSLint is way too opinionated and strict for me.  JSHint allows the style freedom that I prefer (namely comma-first) and still provides a lot of power in terms of validation.

Answer (score 23):

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) has historically been the main tool for this, but several more now exist:

- [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) - a fork of JSLint that is said to be a little less opinionated
- [Closure Linter](https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/) - a linter that checks against the [Google Javascript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)
- [ESLint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint) - a more flexible tool, but newer, and not yet as stable.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't found it yet, you should take a look at Google Closure Compiler. Compiles your JavaScript and finds errors in code. http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_api.html

Answer (score 4):

I tried out ESlint and found it good..you can also add custom rules there..Here is the github repo: https://github.com/nzakas/eslint

Answer (score 2):

[JSAnalyse](http://jsanalyse.codeplex.com/) has just been published on codeplex. It is a tool which analyses the dependencies between javascript files. You can even define the allowed dependencies and `JSAnalysis` checks whether the defined rules are fulfilled or not. That allows to keep track about the `javascript` dependencies even in big projects and to have a clean architecture.

`JSAnalyse` can be executed as a command line tool or configured via the `Visual Studio Layer Diagramm`. It is also easy to integrate into the build. With gated check-ins you can keep the dependencies under control.

Comment: Looks interesting.  The only thing that I don't like from a quick look is that it requires .Net (and Visual Studio?).  I don't know if someone could use this for analyzing their JS in Python, Ruby, Java, etc.  

Regardless, it DOES look interesting and will have to check it out.  Thanks for adding the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There exist a parser called ECMAScript parsing infrastructure for multipurpose analysis (esprima) located at http://esprima.org/ with several example tools that can be used in some analysis

[ECMAScript parsing infrastructure for multipurpose analysis](http://esprima.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from JSLint, JSHint, ESLint, Plato, Google Closure-Linter there's another tool named Esprima.
Here is the link for it: http://esprima.org/

Also, this is the github link for the tool Esprima: https://github.com/ariya/esprima

I faced installation issues while trying out Google Closure-Linter for Windows. But, it does mention on the web page that its support for Windows is experimental. All other tools are easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I have found JSLint which helps correct a lot of common errors and such; however, I'm hoping to find something that I can add my own rules and such to help automate some coding standards stuff that my company is wanting to implement into JavaScript.

http://www.jslint.com/

I need to look into it's extensibility model more.

Comment: I'd love to see something more powerful too, but I haven't found anything yet...

Answer (score 1):

There's a few tools on the [list of tools for static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) at wikipedia that has JavaScript support, you can allso see [JavaScript Debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Debugging) if any of the tools mentioned would help. There's allso a few good tools at [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) (Yahoo! Developer Network), as well as a lot of helpful components.

I've allways used JSLint myself, and that's the only analysis tool for JS I've tried. I've grown more and more fond of JavaScript, but good tools is still a problem. :(

Answer (score 1):

I use Aptana for JavaScript file analysis.   It catches alot of goofs (if condition with a single =).   It also describes the class layout.   I believe it has a jslint implementation embedded in it.