# code duplication in javascript

Tags: javascript, code-duplication

Is there any tool to detect code duplication in JavaScript? I tried  "PMD Duplicate code detector" but it is not supporting .js extension.

Comment: You can always write your own extension for js: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd-parser-howto.html

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend [JSCPD](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jscpd)

## Installation

```
npm install -g jscpd
```

## Run

```
jscpd ./path/to/code
```

(you have several type of reporters, default is console, but you can use html like this: `jscpd -r html ./path/to/code`)

Other solutions:

- JSinspect wasn't good for me because didn't support .ts and .tsx (jscpd supports [150+ formats](https://github.com/kucherenko/jscpd/blob/HEAD/docs/supported_formats.md)
- InteliJ IDEs (I'm a big fan of them) don't seem to work since WebStorm found no duplicated code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JS Inspect](https://github.com/danielstjules/jsinspect) it detects copy-pasted and structurally similar code, also supports `*.js`

#### Installation

```sh
npm install -g jsinspect
```

#### Run

```sh
jsinspect -t 50 ./path/to/src
```

Comment: Caveat from jsinspect's README: `Note: the project has been mostly rewritten for the 0.10 release.`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at this thread (also on stackoverflow):
[Javascript source code analysis ( specifically duplication checking )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627081/javascript-source-code-analysis-specifically-duplication-checking)

Answer (score 0):

IDE can have this functionality. I use IntelliJ, this IDE has a built-in duplicate code checking mechanism at 2 scopes:

- Inline: Duplicate codes are underlined when opened in editor so that developer can easily catch and do refactoring.
- Analysis: Go to menu Analyze->Locate Duplicates.., specify scope to run through and list all duplications.